# Image Not in Right Place Simple HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a facebook image to my header, but something is pushing the facebook image to the far right of the screen. It *should* look like this:

[image]

but, instead, with my current css, it appears like this:
[image]
Any ideas why? I'm still learning proper techniques. I've copied a lot of the CSS from my photoshop design.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.aseimg {
  background-image: url("ASE_large.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 721px;
  top: 77px;
  width: 173px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 61;
}

.NADAlogo {
  background-image: url("NADAlogo.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 916px;
  top: 77px;
  width: 245px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 62;
}

._5_Stars {
  background-image: url("5 Stars.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 1453px;
  top: 97px;
  width: 139px;
  height: 26px;
  z-index: 59;
}

.if_facebook_834722 {
  background-image: url("if_facebook_834722.png");
  position: relative;
  left: 1183px;
  top: 88px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 65;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #193441;
  border: 1px solid #465d65;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 146px;
  z-index: 66;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #465d65;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25%;
  /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* Standard syntax (must be last)*/
}

nav ul li a:active {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HighTech Auto Sales</title>
  <link href="mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a itemprop="url" class="aselink" href="http://www.ase.com/Landing-Pages/Car-Owners/Find-a-Repair-Shop/Shop-Locator.aspx?Address=19111&d=75&sc=us">
      <img class="aseimg" src="../Index%20Images/ASE_large.png"></a>
    <a itemprop="url" class="NADAlogolink" href="http://www.niada.com/member_directory.php?te_mode=map_view">
      <img class="NADAlogo" src="../Index%20Images/NADAlogo.png"></a>
    <a itemprop="url" class="if_facebook_834722">
      <img class="if_facebook_834722" src="../Index%20Images/if_facebook_834722.png"></a>
    <img class="_5_Stars" src="../Index Images/5stars_small.png">

  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="inventory.html">Our Inventory</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Superior Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">HighTech Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact & Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there. You've included a **relative path** for the image in your code. Could you please upload your image online, and update your code to link the image to the online version? We aren't able to see your local image, and linking to an online copy would allow us to see it. It's important to be able to see the problematic image in order to help solve this problem :)

Comment: have you tried applying `position:absolute` to this class `.if_facebook_834722`? It appears to be the only logo rule with `position:relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's sufficient if you *remove* the class `if_facebook_834722` from the `a` link which wraps the facebook image, and change `position:relative` to `postion: absolute` in the CSS rule for the image (`.if_facebook_834722`) - see snippet below.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.aseimg {
  background-image: url("ASE_large.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 721px;
  top: 77px;
  width: 173px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 61;
}

.NADAlogo {
  background-image: url("NADAlogo.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 916px;
  top: 77px;
  width: 245px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 62;
}

._5_Stars {
  background-image: url("5 Stars.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 1453px;
  top: 97px;
  width: 139px;
  height: 26px;
  z-index: 59;
}

.if_facebook_834722 {
  background-image: url("if_facebook_834722.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 1183px;
  top: 88px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 65;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #193441;
  border: 1px solid #465d65;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 146px;
  z-index: 66;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #465d65;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25%;
  /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(25, 25, 25, 1), rgba(126, 158, 173, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  /* Standard syntax (must be last)*/
}

nav ul li a:active {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HighTech Auto Sales</title>
  <link href="mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a itemprop="url" class="aselink" href="http://www.ase.com/Landing-Pages/Car-Owners/Find-a-Repair-Shop/Shop-Locator.aspx?Address=19111&d=75&sc=us">
      <img class="aseimg" src="../Index%20Images/ASE_large.png"></a>
    <a itemprop="url" class="NADAlogolink" href="http://www.niada.com/member_directory.php?te_mode=map_view">
      <img class="NADAlogo" src="../Index%20Images/NADAlogo.png"></a>
    <a itemprop="url">
      <img class="if_facebook_834722" src="../Index%20Images/if_facebook_834722.png"></a>
    <img class="_5_Stars" src="../Index Images/5stars_small.png">

  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="inventory.html">Our Inventory</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Superior Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">HighTech Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact & Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The positioning css is getting applied both to your `<a>` tag and the `<img>` it contains, since they both have the same class. The `<a>` is positioned using the `top` and `left` properties, but then the `<img>` is offset by equal amounts within that.

You will likely want to use different classes so you can handle their positions separately.

Html is not my main area, but I think in general it is considered a bad idea to use absolute positioning in this way... for example, it will require a rewrite if any of your images change size, and won't scale to mobile sizes that well. But for now, hope this will work as a quick fix.